# Как получить обычные текст в боте если он присылается в особом шрифте

Tags: python, бот

Бот должен реагировать на текст, но юзер может прислать текст в другом шрифте, например, если юзер пишет боту "" как мне это обработать и получить простое "when" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте библиотеку [Unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/)

```
import unidecode
input_string = u''
output_string = unidecode.unidecode(input_string)
print(input_string)
print(output_string)
```

Результат:

```
C:\>py test.py

when
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633310/5698975)

Comment: Побочный еффект: оно превращает кирилицу в транслит

Answer (score 1):

Сделай проверку, и если пользователь отправил шрифт выдавай ошибку)

```
print(''.isascii()) -> False
print('w'.isascii()) -> True
```

Можешь придумать как привести их к стандарту, мб этот кусок кода натолкнет на мысли, но и то только с данным шрифтом.

```
if str(ord('w')) == str(ord(''))[:3]:
    print(True)
```

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно обработать все варианты, обязательно

Comment: Желательно бы как то конвертировать все в нормальный шрифт

Comment: Добавил код для размышлений)